# How can i update listView or labels and report to backgroundworker progress changed without using invoke?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm not sure if invoke is the right way to use it. It's working fine but i wonder if i should use invoke or some other way to update gui controls ? And if i want to report to more then 1 gui control ?

Now i'm updating label2 and a listView controls using invoke.
When should i use invoke and when not and then how to update this gui controls without invoking ?

```
private string pathtosearch;
private int countfiles;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    DirSearch(pathtosearch);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
}

void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
            {
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    countfiles += 1;
                    label2.Text = countfiles.ToString();
                });
            }
            DirSearch(d);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt)
    {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(excpt.Message);
        });
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        label1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        pathtosearch = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.TextLength > 0)
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ReportProgress` method to send Message to UI and `ProgressChanged` event to handle the message.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var ex = e.UserState as Exception;
    if(ex!= null)
        ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(ex.Message);
    else
        label2.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();;
}


void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(countfiles++);

            DirSearch(d);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(countfiles, excpt);
    }
}
```

`ReportProgress` can overloaded with two argument: one numeric to report simple "Progress", an thesecond called UserData of type object. if you want send rich information, insert in this argument your custom object or any other existing with the required properties, and on the other side - in  `ProgressChanged` event, "cast" it again to the appropriate type, example:

`ReportProgress`:

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(countfiles, Tuple.Create(currFile, "Copying...", timeRem));
```

`ProgressChanged` event:

```
var data = e.UserState as Tuple<string, string, TimeSpan>;
```